# TeamCity on EC2 - Can access it with private IP not public

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity

We have TeamCity hosted on a Windows Box on AWS EC2.   WE had 0 issues with this in the past and it's been working for years. However, this morning we had to restart the instance and the public IP was changed.

I have been unable to get TeamCity working ever since this happened. I can still access it through the private IP (visible for all internal networks in the EC2 cluster) but I can't access it remotely via the public IP.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What does the admin page show as the Server URL? (admin/admin.html?item=serverConfigGeneral). Might also be worth checking <TeamCity data directory>/config/main-config.xml, although TBH I think this is a networking issue with your AWS config

Comment: Check your VPC settings on AWS, maybe you specifically assigned a security group of :80/:443 to go through to your box. (The ip which is now changed)